# c# application doesn't perform batch file command correctly

Tags: c#, file, batch-file, cmd

```
public void runBatchfile(String batchfilename)
{
   try
   {
      ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(batchfilename);
      processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
      Process batchProcess = new Process();
      batchProcess.StartInfo = processInfo;
      batchProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
      batchProcess.Start();
      batchProcess.WaitForExit();
   }
   catch (Exception r) { }
}

runBatchfile(@"c:\lol.bat");
```

`lol.bat` contains these 2 lines

```
dir c:\ /s /b > c:\filelist.txt
exit
```

and when I run my code all it does is creating a `filelist.txt` file, but doesn't actually perform the rest of the command, which does work if I manually insert it into CMD.

Btw I've tried making the extension .cmd and I also tried without the exit command, without any other results.

please help me :)

Comment: Have you tried executing CMD.EXE instead, passing `/C lol.bat` to it as arguments?

Answer (score 1):

On my Windows 7 64-bit machine with Visual Studio 2010, running this code straight from the IDE doesn't do anything whatsoever.

On a hunch that it might have something to do with permission to write to the root directory of drive C:, I tried running the .exe directly from an Explorer window with admin rights (right-click, Run as Administrator) and that worked.

I'd say it's a permission problem.

Maybe you could redirect the output to a file located elsewhere?

**update**:

I changed the batch file so that the dir command gets redirected to my desktop and it runs just fine.

Comment: Yup, you can't do snot on the C:\ root.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with this as well when calling from C#. The workaround that I usually use is to physically allow it to show the window when running the command. Not sure why this makes a difference but it has worked for me in the past.